# Performance and loadtest Microsoft Botframework fails after only 50 users

Tags: performance, load, botframework, stress-testing

We are trying to simulate 5000 users to test our bot by using JMeter but are facing issues. There are many requests that are canceled while posting back to the client's url. Following are the tools and links we followed as guide and tools to load test:

https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/
https://github.com/damadei/BotServiceStressToolkit

Looking forward to some guidance on how a load test can be run for the botframework and how to handle the "request canceled" in the bot.

EDIT: It works when we execute for up to 50 users, but errors when increasing the number of users. The Post to the client from the bot fails with a canceled result code.

Comment: I'm not putting this in an answer, because don't put links in answers, but that first blog is a bit outdated, even with the  2018 update. I would recommend following the Medium article instead: https://medium.com/microsoftazure/stress-testing-bots-in-azure-bot-service-using-apache-jmeter-part-1-3b440737fd8a. It explains how to set up JMeter and add load, step by step.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But we followed every step in that tutorial. It works when we execute for up to 50 users. But errors on increasing the number of users. The Post to the client from the bot fails with a canceled result code.

Comment: ICIC. What's the status code you're seeing on those 'request cancelled'?

Comment: No status code the result code says "canceled"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot in your question showing this behaviour?